# captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection: Deleagate firing Multiple times

Tags: ios7, avfoundation

captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection: Deleagate firing Multiple times. I need to pass scanned value to server so multiple calls happens to server for one scan

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same question
[Delegate method being invoked multiple times, even after returning to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19093046/2382237)

As Apple documentation says : "this method may be called frequently, your implementation should be efficient to prevent capture performance problems, including dropped metadata objects".

handle multiple invoke do the following :

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    id capturedData;
        if ([metadataObjects count] > 0) {
            // handle your captured data here

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading:) withObject:capturedData waitUntilDone:NO];

        }

}
```

the stopReading: method looks (assuming your _session is AVCaptureSession object and _prevLayer is AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer you used earlier) :

```
-(void)stopReading:(id) data{
    NSLog(@"stop reading");
    [_session stopRunning];
    _session = nil;
    [_prevLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
// do what you want with captured data
    [self.delegate didScanBarCodeWithContext:data];
}
```